# conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in xml

Tags: sql, xml, datetime

i know this type of questions have been asked before but none of them is full fulling my requirements here is my simple code for inserting data into table from an xml but giving error continuously ..i have changed the date into many formats but error did not go.

here is stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_PCMarkAttendance]
    @XMLData xml,   
    @Result Bit output
AS
Begin
 Create table #tempMarkAttendance(
  StSubAssID numeric(18,0) ,  
  Dat Date,
  IsP Bit ,
  IsL Bit   
 ); 
 insert into #tempMarkAttendance(StSubAssID,Dat,IsP,IsL)
    Select 
    attendance.query('StSubAssID').value('.', 'numeric(18,0)') as StSubAssID,
    attendance.query('Dat').value('.', 'Date') as Dat,
    attendance.query('IsP').value('.', 'Bit') as IsP,  
    attendance.query('IsL').value('.', 'Bit') as IsL    
    FROM
    @XMLData.nodes('/StudentList/Student')AS xmlData(attendance)  

    select * from #tempMarkAttendance

set @Result  = 1

End
```

and here is executing it.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @Result bit

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_PCMarkAttendance]     
        @XMLData = N'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<StudentList>
<Student>
<StSubAssId>2</StSubAssId>
<Dat>
2014-01-01</Dat>
<IsP>False</IsP>
<IsL>False</IsL>
</Student>
</StudentList>',
        @Result = @Result OUTPUT

SELECT  @Result as N'@Result'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

and error is:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_PCMarkAttendance, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

another error is when i change type of StSubAssId to numeric(18,0)

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure SP_PCMarkAttendance, Line 12
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source xml you have extra linebreak in the value of `<Dat>` element here:

```
<Dat>
2014-01-01</Dat>
```

So in fact its value not `2014-01-01` as you expecting, but `char(13) + char(10) + '2014-01-01'`.

So you can either remove that line break from original xml, or (if it's not possible by some reason) - you can get this element value in stored procedure as `varchar`, not `date`, then strip off line breaks and cast to date.

```
cast(replace(
      replace(
              attendance.query('Dat').value('.', 'nvarchar(20)'),
              char(13), ''), 
      char(10), '') 
as date)  as Dat
```

Comment: i have another problem when i changed type of StSubAssId to numeric(18,0) it gives me an error

Comment: @AdnanAli I think the reason of that "another error" is the fact you're using `StSubAssId` in source xml, but quering it as `StSubAssID` (notice capital "D" in "ID"). Thus, your query returns empty string (not null) and exception being thrown when converting empty string to numeric.